# error looping thru input tags using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

If I open IE and go to the page I need this works

```vb
LocationURL = "https://secure4.billerweb.com/smg/BillerConsole/inetSrv?sessionHandle=oGWmOV1RQAkSijIxSWs8IjcShm7x4dZir/nuGysZmGsoWXrUY2w9NzE5MTMwNzAw&client=719130700&type=ApplicationMenu&action=Menu"
Set ie = GetIEApp(LocationURL)
Set aHTML = IE.document
Set frames = aHTML.getElementsByTagName("frame")
For Each frame In frames
    Set inputs = frame.contentwindow.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each obj In inputs
        If obj.name = "serviceSelection.inputFieldList[0].accountNumber" Then
            obj.value = "123"
        End If
        If obj.name = "serviceSelection.inputFieldList[0].reEnterAccountNumber" Then
            obj.value = "123"
        End If
        If obj.value = "Continue" Then
            obj.click
        End If
    Next
Next
Public Function GetIEApp(Location)
    Dim objShell
    Dim objWindows
    Dim objWindow
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
    Set objWindows = objShell.Windows
    For Each objWindow In objWindows
        If LCase(Left(objWindow.LocationURL,4)) = "http" Then
            If LCase(Right(objWindow.FullName, 12)) = "iexplore.exe" Then
                If InStr(objWindow.LocationURL,Location) Then
                    Set GetIEApp = objWindow
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set objWindow = Nothing
    Set objWindows = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Function
```

If I use the script to open IE and login then go to the page I get an error

> Object doesnt support this property or method 'frame.contentwindow.document.getElementsByTagName("input")'

```vb
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
IE.Navigate "https://secure4.billerweb.com"
IE.Visible = True
While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
IE.Document.All.Item("loginid").Value = "myid"
IE.Document.All.Item("password").Value = "mypass"
IE.Document.getElementsByName("Login").Item(0).Click
While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
WScript.Sleep 1000
Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("top.header.selectGroup('1', 1)", "JavaScript") 
WScript.Sleep 500
Call IE.document.parentWindow.execScript("top.header.preSubmit('inetSrv?type=WizardService&" & client & "&newBean=true')", "JavaScript") 
While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
WScript.Sleep 1000
Set aHTML = IE.document
Set iframes = aHTML.getElementsByTagName("frame")
For Each frame In iframes
    Set inputs = frame.contentwindow.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each obj In inputs
        If obj.name = "serviceSelection.inputFieldList[0].accountNumber" Then
            obj.value = "123"
        End If
        If obj.name = "serviceSelection.inputFieldList[0].reEnterAccountNumber" Then
            obj.value = "123"
        End If
        If obj.value = "Continue" Then
            obj.click
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Changed
    Set inputs = frame.contentwindow.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
to
    Set inputs = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("input")